# How to access computers with different network segment?

Tags: linux, centos, routing

I have a computer with CENTOS installed as operating system with 2 NIC. One NIC is connected to the internet while the other is connected to a switch that is connected to 3 other computers.

These are the IP address for each computer:

Comp1: 10.11.12.117 (DHCP)
Comp2: 10.11.12.125 (DHCP)
Comp3: 192.168.1.8 (STATIC)

My question is how I can access Comp1 in Comp3?

I've tried to search about routing in centos but I was unable to find a working tutorial. Please guys I really need your help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why is there two different networks (10.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.1.0/24 I guess) on your Switch ? I would say that it is impossible (not really but at least not advised to try to) to access comp1 from comp3 or the opposite in this configuration.

Instead you should configure your DHCP to use addresses inside the same network as Comp3 for Comp1 and Comp2. You NIC on the switch side should also be on this network. On a same switch there should be only one IP network (simplified but a bit true) because the switch doesn't understand how to route IP packets he works on the MAC layer.

Anyway I think you are new to networks and therefore you should read a good introduction to networks book. I would advise Computer Networking: A Top-Down Approach (6th Edition) [James F. Kurose et al.] but that's just my opinion.